# saving more than one value in one Python array position (kinda container)

Tags: python, arrays, collections

I would like to use something as a container but I can't do objects... I believe there is some library or collection or something which could help my.

I want to save a few connected values into one array position:

```
   array = []

   array.append(value1 = 1, value2 = 2, value3 = 3)
   array.append(value1 = 5, value2 = 7, value3 = 10)
   array.append(value1 = 2, value2 = 3, value3 = 3)
```

Something like this... And then I would like to search in this array like

```
   for n in array:
       n.value1 = ....
```

But I'm beginner and don't know much about the language... Can you please help me?

Comment: You need a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: To avoid your next question, dicts are unordered, they won't keep the insertion order like a list so if order matters then look into a OrderedDict

Comment: Order doesn't matter. I need something without unique keys. I need to save only the values. If it was a table it would be in one row. like this: dict{[a=1,b=2], [a=2,b=5], [a=2,b=2],...}.... Then I want to iterate through all "a" values or all "b" values.

Comment: @NaughtyMike, then use a list of lists

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for a dictionary. it can be used like this:

```
d = {"value1": 1, "value2": 2, "value3": 3}
for k in d:
    print("key: {}, value: {}".format(k, d[k]))
```

here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

---

for your problem you 'll need a list of dictionaries. like this:

```
list_of_dict = []

list_of_dict.append({"value1": 1, "value2": 2, "value3": 3})
list_of_dict.append({"value1": 5, "value2": 7, "value3": 10})
list_of_dict.append({"value1": 2, "value2": 3, "value3": 3})

for dct in list_of_dict:
    dct["value1"] = ...
```

Comment: If I understand the concept of dictionary, it saves unique named variables paired with values. For example name:[phone, age]. It means every name is unique. I need something different. I need to save only the values phone and age in one row and I don't care about the key variable. like this: dict{[a=1,b=2], [a=2,b=5], [a=2,b=2],...}

Comment: yes it saves unique keys with corresponding values. keys can not only be strings. if you swap your suggestion you will have exactly what you want: `list_of_dict = [ {"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":2, "b":5}, {"a":2, "b":2}, ... ]`

Comment: @NaughtyMike did it work? if yes please accept an answer, so that the question is listed answered. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment you are looking for a dictionary; see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) or this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YNRc6c0wUA8).

Example code:

```
    dict = {'value1':1,'value2':2,'value3':3}
```